# Regular expression syntax in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I try to write a python scripts to analys a data txt.I want the script to do such things:
find all the time data in one line, and compare them.but this is my first time to write RE syntax.so I write a small script at 1st.

and my script is:

```
import sys
txt = open('1.txt','r')
a = []
for eachLine in txt:
    a.append(eachLine)
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    print pattern.match(a[i])
#print a
```

and the output is always **None**.

my txt is just like the picture:
[image]

what's the problem? plz help me. thx a lot.

and my python is python 2.7.2.my os is windows xp sp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't you miss one of the ":" in you regex? I think you meant

```
re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

The other problems are:

First, if you want to search in the hole text, use `search` instead of `match`. Second, to access your result you need to call group() in the match object returned by your search.

Try it:

```
import sys
txt = open('1.txt','r')
a = []
for eachLine in txt:
    a.append(eachLine)
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    match = pattern.search(a[i])
    print match.group()
#print a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the colons and dots in your regex. Also try using re.search or re.findall instead on the entire text. Like this:

```
import re, sys

text = open("./1.txt", "r").read() # or readlines() to make a list of lines
pattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')

matches = pattern.findall(text)

for i in matches:
     print(i);
```